# Python eval() replace my class associated warning by <string>

Tags: python-2.7, logging, eval

I have methods of my class that contains logging displaying.
So doing :

`logging.warning('message')`

Will display

`17:00:22 WARNING class: message`

But I need at some point to be able to change the logging method on the fly, sometimes it will be debug sometimes warning. So I would like to use a syntax like that:

`type='warning'
eval("logging.%s( message )" % type)`

But it displays that:

`17:00:22 WARNING <string>: message`

Is there a way to make `eval()` displaying the class name instead of `<string>` ?

Thanks

Comment: Code should be code-formatted, not quote-formatted.

Comment: Also, stop using `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is a terrible way to change the logging level of a message on the fly. Use `logging.log` with a level argument:

```
level = logging.WARNING

message = "Low on cheese dip"

logging.log(level, message)
```

This will preserve the information the `logging` module uses to figure out where the logging call was issued from.